# jquery $.ajax not returning value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a return value from an ajax call but I keep getting "undefined"

```
function getUserName(targetName){
```

$.ajax({

```
type: "GET",
url: "http://servername/iMon/queryuser.pl?host="+targetName,
dataType: "XML",
success: function parseUserName(xml){
 var userName = $(xml).find ('firstName').text()+' '+$(xml).find('lastName').text();
 return userName;

   });
```

Comment: ..and it's not too late to revisit your old questions and marked what worked for you!

Comment: Sorry that was a noob mistake. I went back and accepted my answers. If I add an alert for userName before the return, it shows the correct information, so I don't believe it is an issue with the XML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't return a value. Ajax (Asynchronous JavaScript and XML) is **Asynchronous**.

The execution context is broken because parseUserName is called in response to an event being fired, it isn't called by your getUserName function.

Write the success handler to do whatever it is you want to do with the data.

Comment: I will just have to do a request within another function so I can use the values it gets. Thanks.